# Ensure my location marker is drawn above the others

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-utils

I’m plotting content on a `GoogleMap` using the map clustering utility library from google.

I have lots of items representing pictures. Depending on zoom level, they are clustered or not. I’m managing clustering with a `DefaultClusterRenderer` subclass.

At the same time, I want to draw a marker representing the device location. That is a totally different marker which should **not** be clustered. Because of that I’m dealing with this single marker outside the `ClusterManager` / `ClusterRenderer` cycle, i.e. calling `mMap.addMarker()`.

The issue with that is that sometimes, depending on when we get the device location, and moreover during zoom in/out, my location marker is drawn **below** the other points and clusters. I want to have the exact opposite behavior, i.e. location marker always on top.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: You can use the zIndex value to determine which appears on top.

Comment: Hi @KMB, could you please elaborate on that? I see no zIndex.

Comment: There is no `zIndex (float zIndex)` for `MarkerOptions`. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771569/google-maps-v2-marker-zordering-set-to-top