# How can I define the order of my markers in google maps with kotlin?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I have many markers in googlemaps which overlap at some points. Now I want to define which markers are on top of other markers. Is there any way to do so? My Markers seem to just randomly overlap.

I am adding my Markers with:

```
mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(LatLng(breitengrade_live[k], langengrade_live[k])).title(Busname).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(Bitmap_copy))).
```

Comment: This link might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771569/google-maps-v2-marker-zordering-set-to-top/14771740#14771740

Comment: works like a charm thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way as such. But you can give IDs to the marker and then check if their lat and long is same